# Returning conditional JSon files for one action on Rails

Tags: ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a controller that returns different instance variables based on params[:type]. I would also like to to return different JSon files based on params[:type]. I am justing Jbuilder to create this JSon file, but it seems like I can only have 1 JSon file associated with each action. How do I get around this?

Specifically, the controller looks something like this:

```
@all_posts = Post.all
if params[:type] == 'abc'
  @result = @all_posts.where(:type => 'abc')
elsif params[:type] == 'def'
  @result = @all_posts.where(:type => 'def')
end
```

I have created a Jbuilder file that looks something like this

```
json.array!(@result) do |counter|
  json.id counter["id"]
end
```

However, right now, it Json file is not returning anything since it does not detect the params[:type] key. What can I do here to solve this issue? The Jbuilder file returns a variable if it is not conditional on the params[:key], however, I want it to returned JSon file to be dependent on the params[:type].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is more or less what you're looking for...

```
def index
  @all_posts = Post.all
  template = "" # The name of the jbuilder template you want to render (without the extension)

  if params[:type] == 'abc'
    @result = @all_posts.where(:type => 'abc')
    template = "abc_template"
  elsif params[:type] == 'def'
    @result = @all_posts.where(:type => 'def')
    template = "def_template"
  end

  render template
end
```

See sections 2.2.2 and 2.2.3 at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html